# Drop duplicate rows conditionally - Pecking order

Tags: pandas

I have a df as below

```
A        B_x        B_y                       C
1        USD        GBP, USD, EUR             V1
1        USD                                  V2
2        GBP        GBP, USD, EUR             V1
3        JPY        GBP, USD, EUR             V1
3        JPY                                  V4
4        SEK        GBP, USD, EUR             v5
```

The idea is if B_y contains B_x then the value of C must be chosen from that row else C must be chosen from the row wherever B_y is blank (Blank is a wildcard). I should end up with a unique row for every A (wherever a match can be found).

For the above the result df should be

```
A        B_x           B_y               C
1        USD           GBP,USD,EUR       V1
2        GBP           GBP,USD,EUR       V1
3        JPY                             v4
```

For A = 4 no valid matches are found hence no entries in the output.

My approach: I have tried the following.

```
df[~df.duplicated(['A', keep=False]) | df.apply(lambda x: x.B_x in x.B_y, axis=0) | df.apply(lambda x: x.B_y='', axis=0)]
```

Expectedly this matches rows which has both B_y with values 'GBP, USD, EUR' and row with the blank (wildcard).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to create the mask by `zip`:

```
mask = [x in y or not y for x, y in zip(df["B_x"], df["B_y"])]
print (df.loc[mask].drop_duplicates("A", keep="first"))

   A  B_x            B_y   C
0  1  USD  GBP, USD, EUR  V1
2  2  GBP  GBP, USD, EUR  V1
4  3  JPY                 V4
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much Henry

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with pandas:

```
 data = [{'A': '1', 'B_x': 'USD', 'B_y': 'GBP, USD, EUR', 'C': 'V1'},
 {'A': '1', 'B_x': 'USD', 'B_y': '', 'C': '  V2'},
 {'A': '2', 'B_x': 'GBP', 'B_y': 'GBP, USD, EUR', 'C': 'V1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B_x': 'JPY', 'B_y': 'GBP, USD, EUR', 'C': 'V1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B_x': 'JPY', 'B_y': '', 'C': 'V4'},
 {'A': '4', 'B_x': 'SEK', 'B_y': 'GBP, USD, EUR', 'C': 'v5'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Identify row where B_y contains B_x
df['B_y contains B_x'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B_x'] in row['B_y'], axis=1)

#Sort DataFrame so that the rows where B_y contain B_x are first, otherwhise show the wildcard row first
df = df.sort_values(['A','B_x','B_y contains B_x','B_y'], ascending= [True, True, False, True])

#Remove the keys where no valid match was found
df = df[df['B_y contains B_x'] | df['B_x'].isin(list(df[df['B_x'].duplicated()].B_x))].drop_duplicates(['B_x'],keep='first')
del df['B_y contains B_x']
```

**Output:**

```
|    |   A | B_x   | B_y           | C   |
|---:|----:|:------|:--------------|:----|
|  0 |   1 | USD   | GBP, USD, EUR | V1  |
|  2 |   2 | GBP   | GBP, USD, EUR | V1  |
|  4 |   3 | JPY   |               | V4  |
```